# HttpServletResponse as an argument

Tags: http, servlets

I am pretty new to servlets and I would like to ask a kind of silly question.

I have a method that has an HttpServletResponse argument and I need to call this method from my main method to run the Java program.

The thing is I do not know what should I pass as value for this argument.

Let's say I have this class that comes from CrystalReports:

```
private static void exportIt(ReportClientDocument clientDoc, ExportOptions exportOptions, HttpServletResponse response, boolean attachment, String mimeType, String extension)
        throws ReportSDKExceptionBase, IOException {

        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new BufferedInputStream(clientDoc.getPrintOutputController().export(exportOptions));

            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            response.setContentType(mimeType);
            if (attachment)
            {
                String name = clientDoc.getReportSource().getReportTitle();
                if (name == null)
                {
                    name = "CrystalReportViewer";
                }
                else
                {
                    name = name.replaceAll("\"", "");
                }

                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                        "attachment; filename=\"" + name + "."+extension+"\"");
            }
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            while (is.read(data) > -1) {
                os.write(data);
            }
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

When I try to call the exportIt method I need to pass something in the HTTPServletResponse but I do not know what is the exact value.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: You don't need a main method since this method is managed in your servlet container. All your business code must me handled in a servlet class that you create and from which you get HttpServletResponse and HttpServletRequest.

Comment: @AbassA Thank you for your response! So I will need to create a servlet class that I will call this method right?

Comment: yes, that's it!